# ICTU/zap-baseline - Authenticated login is not scanning post login urls

Tags: authentication

I have created a temporary login at https://demoqa.com I can see authentication but the urls after authentication are not followed, the same happens on my own website and http://altoromutual.com.

I tried adding logs but am getting more detail than code.

I presume I must be missing something.

```
   docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t ictu/zap2docker-weekly zap-baseline.py -I -j -d -t https://demoqa.com -r testreport.html --hook=/zap/auth_hook.py -z "auth.loginurl=https://demoqa.com/login auth.username=username auth.password=password auth.include=https://demoqa.*"
```

***These are not the correct login details***

Full logs
https://github.com/ICTU/zap-baseline/issues/43

Logs

```
    2021-11-23 17:12:10,965 Target: https://demoqa.com
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,070 Trigger hook: cli_opts, args: 1
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,071 Using port: 46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,072 Trigger hook: start_zap, args: 2
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,072 Extra params passed by ZAP: ['-config', 'spider.maxDuration=1', '-addonupdate', '-addoninstall', 'pscanrulesBeta', 'auth.loginurl=https://demoqa.com/login', 'auth.username=username', 'auth.password=password', 'auth.include=https://demoqa.']
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,072 _get_zap_param auth.loginurl: https://demoqa.com/login
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,073 _get_zap_param auth.username: username
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,073 _get_zap_param auth.password: password
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,073 _get_zap_param_list auth.include: ['https://demoqa.']
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,073 Starting ZAP
    2021-11-23 17:12:11,074 Params: ['zap-x.sh', '-daemon', '-port', '46852', '-host', '0.0.0.0', '-config', 'database.recoverylog=false', '-config', 'api.disablekey=true', '-config', 'api.addrs.addr.name=.', '-config', 'api.addrs.addr.regex=true', '-config', 'spider.maxDuration=1', '-addonupdate', '-addoninstall', 'pscanrulesBeta', 'auth.loginurl=https://demoqa.com/login', 'auth.username=username', 'auth.password=password', 'auth.include=https://demoqa.']
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,154 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,254 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/core/view/version/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,255 ZAP Version D-2021-11-15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,255 Took 13 seconds
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,255 Trigger hook: zap_started, args: 2
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,257 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,324 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/ascan/action/updateScanPolicy/?scanPolicyName=Default+Policy&apikey=&attackStrength=LOW HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,327 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,348 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/replacer/action/addRule/?description=Scanner&enabled=True&matchType=REQ_HEADER&matchRegex=False&matchString=X-Scanner&apikey=&replacement=ZAP HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,353 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,445 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/context/action/newContext/?contextName=ctx-zap-docker&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 17
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,448 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,495 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/context/action/includeInContext/?contextName=ctx-zap-docker&regex=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.%2A&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,496 Included https://demoqa.*
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,497 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,521 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/context/action/includeInContext/?contextName=ctx-zap-docker&regex=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com.%2A&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,522 Included https://demoqa.com.*
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,523 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,552 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/context/action/excludeFromContext/?contextName=ctx-zap-docker&regex=.%2Alogout.%2A&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,553 Excluded .logout.
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,555 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,572 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/context/action/excludeFromContext/?contextName=ctx-zap-docker&regex=.%2Auitloggen.%2A&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,573 Excluded .uitloggen.
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,575 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,593 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/context/action/excludeFromContext/?contextName=ctx-zap-docker&regex=.%2Aafmelden.%2A&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,594 Excluded .afmelden.
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,596 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,611 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/context/action/excludeFromContext/?contextName=ctx-zap-docker&regex=.%2Asignout.%2A&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,612 Excluded .signout.
    2021-11-23 17:12:24,612 Start webdriver
    2021-11-23 17:12:25,624 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"profile": "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", "args": ["-headless"]}}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "marionette": true, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"profile": "UEsDBBQAAAAIAIyJd1N0S+jrjgMAAPcMAAAHAAAAdXNlci5qc6VWTW/UMBC98ytQTyCx1rbABU6lFAkJUcSq4mg59mTjrmMbe7zp/nvGyaYsbb6AWz7e89hvZt44RQjcByhfnBXBNfTGlKtZo61yDVOp9gysKAyos1fPMSR4+f5ZesoxAiGEZE/ApTBxBG2hQVGwFAzhzkThEr4rjLC7sym8F1tYtn5EETB5lhmEXE+jKlfDEblgL49Z3O3p5FoBqyM6266it9YFGFmAPqkb+6MVOJ6vmbYY3O33L9Phc1Jqcc9lFSgwjzJoj5wU56jrHPT1epiwDBnAu4BcGMPvIod7CR61s3Ew6XdiL7plmetgLFau+Wyv6NEZGCRZwMaFHZOCKHtY5XjCrAiw13ImrxFkChoPTMa+HEeAj5PTgJFZr9lSm2IyoZTO5xQzizRQqECHC1zIrCBPlNsUERSXEHBYzRNSjClHfCBp+gBhhtXpwa3IsnLYgx0J9KAimsiIGelErNaWwOd/IoX3LHlFPc1EQjes9QloUVMqHb0RB1DX5+vNV4eUdSK8GQG7xhonFJWwpWyEtsB+VGA3OU/abqdjXd9+uWR9Y04aV4t8zbp8zZmctjuqeLDUIGR3XTlczGHJvDo3HQe7siT8SE33oABCZWUAQdJOP+kQ8ZK0kCMN92BYooT2mVRbaJ+njFqYRoSlxgsiyOpYFnNQU8bksw30g2DMcSHmUiV3pW0EaHukJBfkMohYzUSpwBgmK5C7j1CKZPBD92eaRtMmMjq2vbFXxsWZo5ygbyjjw2BSRHQum1WtQBisune2yAMn+MnnVrn+R3YfvcwF9T39/faN227zR9m5/1/swzuj5YHlj5tU1LrN8//yv7UfL3839NAysEfnyAbJIVw4bnzyopOHJDlYa7VtWyvyUrvlWfnhGNkjbFu4rYl+7MgbSezsz+frUXhhnNwZHXG6Ik4YbYFfudrTECi0ySZv9bZCc5ilLrHwp3BL/l0ebkcb6eSKMKVqfynoXH519MEVDWNMcXjlnlIh0gWv0rE6rPJvT9NzZcBuMVvCxdu3f9L6pWlqUT6McQ0vDlx1njC4N08W4zHm7ua1U8IsvKOU2gA9MRc0tQXvajRfu2bwEYOWyB/ThkLl+6UlK6yhLiBs2tcRuXKZ7zSyo2z9OD2W8uDBewqCoQgYDqyToj35xRx2UqSn8AB37Tgb3Mm912T7lC2Wj0w1Qe5PjJ9Jh7EIvylNpSlM7qIBxi9QSwECFAMUAAAACACMiXdTdEvo644DAAD3DAAABwAAAAAAAAAAAAAApIEAAAAAdXNlci5qc1BLBQYAAAAAAQABADUAAACzAwAAAAA=", "args": ["-headless"]}}}
    2021-11-23 17:12:25,624 Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:53503
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,302 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 200 693
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,302 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,303 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/window/rect {"x": null, "y": null, "width": 1920, "height": 1080}
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,331 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/window/rect HTTP/1.1" 200 50
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,332 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,332 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/window/maximize {}
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,587 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/window/maximize HTTP/1.1" 200 50
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,588 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,588 authenticate using webdriver against URL: https://demoqa.com/login
    2021-11-23 17:12:29,588 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/url {"url": "https://demoqa.com/login"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:31,480 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/url HTTP/1.1" 200 14
    2021-11-23 17:12:31,480 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,482 automatically finding login elements
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,482 Trying to find element username
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,482 Built xpath: //input[(translate(@id, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='username') and (@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='number' or not(@type))]
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,482 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element {"using": "xpath", "value": "//input[(translate(@id, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='username') and (@type='text' or @type='email' or @type='number' or not(@type))]"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,507 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element HTTP/1.1" 200 88
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,507 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,507 Found element username by id
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,508 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/b854ce8d-4a2b-44e8-b965-a1ff033eedae/clear {"id": "b854ce8d-4a2b-44e8-b965-a1ff033eedae"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,540 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/b854ce8d-4a2b-44e8-b965-a1ff033eedae/clear HTTP/1.1" 200 14
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,540 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,541 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/b854ce8d-4a2b-44e8-b965-a1ff033eedae/value {"text": "username", "value": ["u", "s", "e", "r", "n", "a", "m", "e"], "id": "b854ce8d-4a2b-44e8-b965-a1ff033eedae"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,738 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/b854ce8d-4a2b-44e8-b965-a1ff033eedae/value HTTP/1.1" 200 14
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,738 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,738 Filled the username element
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,738 Trying to find element password
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,739 Built xpath: //input[(translate(@id, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='password') and (@type='text' or @type='password' or not(@type))]
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,739 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element {"using": "xpath", "value": "//input[(translate(@id, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='password') and (@type='text' or @type='password' or not(@type))]"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,744 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element HTTP/1.1" 200 88
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,745 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,745 Found element password by id
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,745 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/e9d401fd-712b-46b4-8686-6f694191e950/clear {"id": "e9d401fd-712b-46b4-8686-6f694191e950"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,761 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/e9d401fd-712b-46b4-8686-6f694191e950/clear HTTP/1.1" 200 14
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,762 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,763 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/e9d401fd-712b-46b4-8686-6f694191e950/value {"text": "passwprd", "value": ["p", "a", "s", "s", "w", "o", "r", "d"], "id": "e9d401fd-712b-46b4-8686-6f694191e950"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,840 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/e9d401fd-712b-46b4-8686-6f694191e950/value HTTP/1.1" 200 14
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,840 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,840 Filled the password element
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,841 Trying to find element login
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,841 Built xpath: //[(translate(@id, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='login') and (@type='submit' or @type='button' or button)]
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,841 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element {"using": "xpath", "value": "//[(translate(@id, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='login') and (@type='submit' or @type='button' or button)]"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,854 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element HTTP/1.1" 200 88
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,854 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,854 Found element login by id
    2021-11-23 17:12:36,854 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/0c7a8e85-118d-4f78-a862-9cce041f094b/click {"id": "0c7a8e85-118d-4f78-a862-9cce041f094b"}
    2021-11-23 17:12:37,106 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/element/0c7a8e85-118d-4f78-a862-9cce041f094b/click HTTP/1.1" 200 14
    2021-11-23 17:12:37,106 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:37,106 Clicked the login element
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,077 Finding authentication cookies
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,079 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,087 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/addSessionToken/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&sessionToken=session_token&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,089 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,107 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/createEmptySession/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&apikey=&session=auth-session HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,108 GET http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/cookie {}
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,118 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "GET /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/cookie HTTP/1.1" 200 1175
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,119 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,121 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,126 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/setSessionTokenValue/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&session=auth-session&sessionToken=_ga&tokenValue=GA1.2.121671487.1637687551&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,127 Cookie added: _ga=GA1.2.121671487.1637687551
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,130 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,135 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/setSessionTokenValue/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&session=auth-session&sessionToken=_gid&tokenValue=GA1.2.1784877309.1637687551&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,136 Cookie added: _gid=GA1.2.1784877309.1637687551
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,138 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,145 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/setSessionTokenValue/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&session=auth-session&sessionToken=_gat_gtag_UA_109033876_1&tokenValue=1&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,146 Cookie added: _gat_gtag_UA_109033876_1=1
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,148 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,153 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/setSessionTokenValue/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&session=auth-session&sessionToken=token&tokenValue=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6InBldGVwZXJmZWN0IiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJUZXN0IVRlc3QhMTEiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mzc2ODc1NTZ9.xYKcRuxRIymzfy2809SKlVQOCxFDKa0VDTs66l06qJg&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,154 Cookie added: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6InBldGVwZXJmZWN0IiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJUZXN0IVRlc3QhMTEiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mzc2ODc1NTZ9.xYKcRuxRIymzfy2809SKlVQOCxFDKa0VDTs66l06qJg
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,156 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,160 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/setSessionTokenValue/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&session=auth-session&sessionToken=expires&tokenValue=2021-11-30T17%253A12%253A36.979Z&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,161 Cookie added: expires=2021-11-30T17%3A12%3A36.979Z
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,164 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,169 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/setSessionTokenValue/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&session=auth-session&sessionToken=userID&tokenValue=201225b8-58b3-4284-b54c-0e9447a8e374&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,170 Cookie added: userID=201225b8-58b3-4284-b54c-0e9447a8e374
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,173 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,178 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/setSessionTokenValue/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&session=auth-session&sessionToken=userName&tokenValue=username&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,179 Cookie added: userName=username
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,182 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,187 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/action/setActiveSession/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com&session=auth-session&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,193 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,200 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/httpSessions/view/activeSession/?site=https%3A%2F%2Fdemoqa.com HTTP/1.1" 200 33
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,201 Active session: auth-session
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,201 Finding authentication headers
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,202 POST http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/execute/sync {"script": "var ls = window.localStorage, items = {}; for (var i = 0, k; i < ls.length; ++i) items[k = ls.key(i)] = ls.getItem(k); return items; ", "args": []}
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,216 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "POST /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff/execute/sync HTTP/1.1" 200 12
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,216 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,217 DELETE http://127.0.0.1:53503/session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff {}
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,914 http://127.0.0.1:53503 "DELETE /session/3a1afbcf-0114-4b1b-abf6-e76a1178bcff HTTP/1.1" 200 14
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,915 Finished Request
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,916 Tune
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,916 Disable all tags
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,920 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,930 http://localhost:46852 "GET http://zap/JSON/pscan/action/disableAllTags/?apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,930 Set max pscan alerts
    2021-11-23 17:12:42,932 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:46852
```

Comment: FYI the official ZAP baseline scan now supports authentication, so thats another option for you. https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/baseline-scan/

Comment: For support of the ICTU baseline you'd have to reach out to the ICTU team. (Arguably you should remove the ZAP tag on the post ;) )